# Tests for paired data

Tags: paired-data, pre-post-comparison

We have a paired data of before and after drug and placebo use and its effect on Systemic Blood pressure.

The question at hand is

" There is more than one way to make use of the baseline measurements (contained in the BloodPressureBefore.csv file). Try a few different ways of incorporating these into your analysis. Make sure to clearly state how you are using these measurements in each method you try, as well as include any relevant summaries/output. Clearly explaining HOW you have used the baseline measurements is more important than any numeric answers you may provide."

I am taking a beginner's course in stats, and my few basic options are.

1. Paired t-test
2. Wilconxon Signed rant test
3. Anova

How would you guys approach it?

TIA

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: See this very helpful post [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs)